# Why bootstrap table bind dash

Tags: database, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

when i bind data to hard code JSON string then it bind perfectly,please help i wasted many hours behind this in trying different different things.
my ajax call -

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "Settings.aspx/Fn_GetEmployeeList",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    debugger;
    $('#tblEmployeeList').bootstrapTable({
      data: [response.d]
    });
  },
  error: function (result) {
    alert("Error");
  }
});
```

This is my bootstrap table where I want to bind data.data field are the field come from database through Ajax call and in JSON format.

Image:

[image]